# Image blur in android

Tags: android

I have taken thumbnail image from gallery  which is smaller in size and resized into 300*300 size.

By doing that the image looking so blurred.

**getting image from gallery**

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        switch (requestCode) {
        case 0:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    flag = 1;
                    Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex); // file
                    // path
                    // of
                    // selected
                    // image
                    cursor.close();

                    // Convert file path into bitmap image using below line.

                    yourSelectedImage = download.getResizedBitmap(
                        image.decodeImage(filePath),270,228);

                    // put bitmapimage in your imageview
                    profile_image.setImageBitmap(
                            yourSelectedImage);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Image resizing**

```
public  Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) 
    {
        try
        {
            if(bm!=null)
            {
            int width = bm.getWidth();
            int height = bm.getHeight();
            float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
            float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
            // create a matrix for the manipulation
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            // resize the bit map
            matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
            // recreate the new Bitmap
            resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true); 


            }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return resizedBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: There is no question here! What is it you want to know?

Comment: How to solve the blurring issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images get blurred when you enlarge them (unless you are using an vector image and you are using a bitmap). Your `getResizedBitmap` method doesn't do anything much other than stretching the image to fit the new size. The only way you are going to solve your problem is by selecting larger images (but then eventually you will run into the aspect ratio problem, so you should really rethink your scaling algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

Of course enlarging a bitmap image will be pixelated..

Comment: Find an alternative image that is larger. Too bad for u.